# I am getting an error when using ArgumentException, calling for an assembly reference, what is this?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Exercise
{
    public abstract class Gun
    {
        public Gun(string name, int bullets)
        {
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Bullets
        {
            get { return Bullets; }
            set 
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentЕxception("Bullets cannot be below 0");
                }
                else
                {
                    Bullets = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that I am trying to run. I have checked and the framework is the same, which was an answer to a similar question. I am using VS code and have all the essential extensions downloaded. Do you have any idea what could be giving this error?

> The type or namespace name 'ArgumentЕxception' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have a `using System` clause at the top of this file?

Comment: Yes, I have it at the very top. It's the only library I have implemented. Should I add other libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the "E" you're using. It's [`U+0415`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0415/index.htm), or "Cyrillic capital letter ie"... instead of the ASCII capital E.

Just retype that `E` and all will be well.

When you have errors that don't quite make sense like this, if you *suspect* it may be an odd character issue (either an incorrect character like in this case, or unprintable characters) you might want to use a little utility I've got on a web page - my [Unicode explorer](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Unicode#explorer). Just paste the text (in this case I copied "ArgumentЕxception") into the text box, and have a look at the characters it consists of.

You should also consider *how* you got into this state - if you can work out how you ended up with a non-ASCII character there, you might be able to avoid it in the future.

Comment: I see, I didn't know this tpe of error could cause this, but I have been pasting the code fro ArgumentException from Athanasios and not using my own. I also retyped it after, seeing your answer, but it still doesn't work.
EDIT: THIS IS WRONG IT. THE CHARACTER WAS THE PROBLEM. I AM SO SORRY!

Comment: @MartinSvilenski: The code in your *question* has the problem, and has from the very first revision. I'm sure Athanasios just copy/pasted *your* code. Try just copy/pasting `ArgumentException` from this comment. If retyping it directly causes an issue, that suggests you might want to change your keyboard settings.

Comment: Edited my previous comment, you were right @JonSkeet